# Custom sort order in a report

Tags: reporting, report-builder

I have a field with the following possible values:

"1-4","5-9","10-16","16+"

This is the order I want them to appear in a matrix report. But they appear in this order: "1-4","10-16","16+","5-9"

[image]

Because they are text and are sorted as text. How do I fix this?

Edited to add a picture.

Comment: Is that possible to make formula with type of number and sort by that field?

Comment: I can "bucket" the field, but then what's the point of having the summary field in the first place? I want to have this field easily available for all report generators, with one definition, not one that's created "on the fly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to define a custom sort function for standard SFDC reporting. First solutions that come to mind are:

1. Edit the picklist values to better suit the alphabetical sort, like:

   - A 1-5
   - B 5-10
   - C 10+
2. Rely on a formula field to customize your sorting, and then use this second field for your reports.

Comment: It is a formula field, based on the actual number in the field. Do I still need to edit the values to be alphabetical?

Comment: Then why not sort by the original number field?

Comment: That field isn't on the report and I don't want to add it. It's a matrix report, I want to summarize by it.

Comment: Tweaking values in the formula to look like '01 - 05' and '05 - 09' should allow to sort it correctly

Comment: I'm marking this answered. Really the answer is we have to change the category names, or not use them.